# have asp:login control send data to a different page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on a site where I have a username and password box via an asp.net login control and I would like when you click login in the control that it sends the login request via my secure page.
I already have single-sign-on working I just want the login data to traverse over SSL.

anyone know if this is possible and how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

The decision to use SSL is made by the WebRequest class, based on the URI it is given. If the URI begins with "https:", SSL is used; if the URI begins with "http:", an unencrypted connection is used.

Comment: your not understanding the question. I have single sig-on on implemented and the actual login process is handled on a completely different website. I just wanted to put a login control on the other site for ease of access and wire it up to the second site via ssl